# Full repository queue manager as Multi Instance

Tags: ibm-mq

Why it is not recommended to have full repository queue manager in a cluster as multi-instance?

Recommendation is from the in webcast presentation "[Implementation Considerations for Multi-Instance Queue Managers in WebSphere MQ Cluster Environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27018127)".

Comment: Please site the reference to this recommendation.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27018127&aid=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webcast presentation "[Implementation Considerations for Multi-Instance Queue Managers in WebSphere MQ Cluster Environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27018127)" referenced was from 2010.

Two limitations that contribute to the recommendation are given earlier in the presentation:

Page 16:

> - Pre - 7.0.1 repositories will have to have a channel to both machines that Multi-Instance queue manager is using
> - Stuck messages on SYSTEM.CLUSTER.TRANSMIT.QUEUE

Page 17:

> - z/OS
>
>   - CONNAME attribute 48 character limit
>
>     - Long hostnames may not fit

Given that the last version of MQ prior to 7.0.1 went out of support September 30th 2012, the first limitation above should no longer be a consideration however at the time the presentation was given there was still more than two years of support left for v6.

The second limitation above would only be a concern if you have z/OS (Mainframe) MQ partial repositories connecting to a distributed full repository.

While those two limitations above may not apply to you now, there may be no reason to make them MI since you already have  redundancy with the recommended two Full repositories for a cluster.